# Ember computed property on service

Tags: ember.js, service, ember-data, ember-cli

I was hoping to have a computed property off of a service object and have had trouble doing so. I have a shopping cart service and a shop route which allows customers to pick items and add them to the cart. I have no problem adding them to the cart, but when I try to add a computed property from the controller or route, they never fire when the objects (cart and cartTotal) change.

Here's the cart service:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  cart: [],
  currentTotal: 0,
  addToCart(product){
    // TODO add promise here
    this.get('cart').push(product);
    this.get('updateTotal')(this);
  },

  updateTotal: function(context){
    debugger;
    var total = 0;
    context.get('cart').forEach(function(product){
      total += parseInt(product.get('price'));
    }.bind(total));
    context.set('currentTotal', total);
  },
 ...
```

And here's my shop controller:

```
const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  cart: service('cart'),
  products: null,
  productGroupings: null,
  menus: null,
  currentMenu: Ember.computed.oneWay('cart.currentMenu'),
  menus: Ember.computed.oneWay('cart.menus'),
  cartTotal: Ember.computed.oneWay('cart.cartTotal'),
  ...
```

It also fails with observers setting the properties as well as using alias inplace of 'oneWay.' This also fails on the route. I'm currently running Ember 1.13.8.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You simply forgot to add .property() at the end of both functions:

```
addToCart(product){
  // TODO add promise here
  this.get('cart').push(product);
  this.get('updateTotal')(this);
}.property('cart', 'updateTotal'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that I forgot to add this.notifyPropertyDidChange around the push. Without the set, the computed properties never fired. Adding that fixed it right up.